# How to decode gerrit code review rest api responses

Tags: python, rest, gerrit

I've read this for querying gerrit https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html

But even in the examples in the document the response from gerrit has this garbled string at the start of what looks like a valid array of change detail records, and this means it is not valid json.
I'm using the requests module for python to access the /changes end point.
Has anyone successfully decoded the "json" output from the gerrit code review server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to strip the ")]}" prefix of the Gerrit output.

See more details in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#output).

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the string at the start and I did want to strip i but I thought that would be too hacky and i must be doing something wrong.